# Can an Ember component inherit parent component properties without passing in the template?

Tags: ember.js

I have a few components that come with parent and child parts. As an example, consider an Ember component as a solution to a tab menu, which could look something like this.

```
{{#tab-set}}
  {{tab-single title=PageA selected=true}}
  {{tab-single title=PageB}}
  {{tab-single title=PageC}}
{{/tab-set}}
```

The tabs need a way to know which should be selected. The **tab-set** could have a property called **deselector**. This could be passed to all the child **tab-singles**. When a **tab-single** is clicked, it would toggle the **deselector** property, which would be observed by all the other child **tab-single**, ensuring they all all deselected. This would then allow the clicked **tab-single** to become the selected tab.

It might look something like this...

```
{{#tab-set}}
  {{tab-single title=PageA selected=true deselector=deselector}}
  {{tab-single title=PageB deselector=deselector}}
  {{tab-single title=PageC deselector=deselector}}
{{/tab-set}}
```

For every tab I ever make, I'll need to pass in the **deselector.** Is there a way that I can set the **tab-single** to always look for a **deselector** property in its parent **tab-set**?

That is, is there a way that a child component can always look for a property from its parent component, without it having to passed in the template?

Ta

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a way to kind of do it with contextual components. What you'll need to do is to yield the `tab-single` component with the deselector already bound, instead of using `tab-single` directly.

[I've made a working Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/35a381fa4f9c6f470273e2c8b133dff0) so you can check it out.

First, we yield the component with the `deselector` action bound. I'm using the hash helper to construct an object in-line. This makes the exported variable more structured.

```
 // app/templates/components/tab-set.hbs
 {{yield (hash tab=(component 'tab-single' deselector=deselector))}}
```

To be able to bind the `deselector` action like that, means that we have to pass it to `tab-set`. Since we're using the block form and `yield`, we will have what are called block params. Think of the `{{each array as |item|}}` syntax. Item can be whatever name you see more fit:

```
 {{#tab-set deselector=(action 'deselector') as |opts|}}
   {{opts.tab page="1"}}
   {{opts.tab page="2"}}
   {{opts.tab page="3"}}
 {{/tab-set}}
```

Hope this adequately answers your questions :)